# Zombie.js doesn't return complete HTML

Tags: javascript, node.js, zombie.js

I just tested Zombie.js and I let it visit the login page on StackOverflow. My code is as follows:

```
var Browser = require("zombie");

// Load the page from localhost
browser = new Browser()
browser.visit("http://stackoverflow.com/users/login/", function () {
    browser.wait(3000, function (){
        console.log(browser.html());
        console.log(browser.success);
    });
});
```

I tried looking around, and I know that Zombie.js runs scripts and sort of compresses the HTML, but in this case, the entire `body` of the code is missing.

**I don't believe this is relevant,** but the HTML code returned is:

```
<html><head>

    <title>Log In - Stack Overflow</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png" />
    <link rel="search" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" title="Stack Overflow" href="/opensearch.xml" />


    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://edge.quantserve.com/quant.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/js/stub.js?v=8a629d6e9fb6"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=24fdd40e5473" />

    <meta http-equiv="X-XRDS-Location" content="http://stackoverflow.com/yadis" />
    <script src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/third-party/openid-jquery.js?v=8b3167d0ee55" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.write('<style type="text/css">.login-page .script-only { display: block; }<\/style>');
        $(function() {
            openid.init('openid_identifier', '', 'http://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/openid/openid-logos.png?v=8', true);
        });
    </script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        StackExchange.init({"stackAuthUrl":"https://stackauth.com","serverTime":1353439370,"styleCode":true,"enableUserHovercards":true,"site":{"name":"Stack Overflow","description":"Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers","isNoticesTabEnabled":true,"recaptchaPublicKey":"6LdchgIAAAAAAJwGpIzRQSOFaO0pU6s44Xt8aTwc","enableSocialMediaInSharePopup":true},"user":{"fkey":"8074e87bcb0a1a15cc69db799d304930","isAnonymous":true}});
        StackExchange.using.setCacheBreakers({"js/prettify-full.js":"c862bf93b3ec","js/moderator.js":"37bba549a03e","js/full-anon.js":"bcd6f2e0d542","js/full.js":"87618162bac4","js/wmd.js":"89ec12ce09df","js/third-party/jquery.autocomplete.min.js":"e5f01e97f7c3","js/mobile.js":"6eb68240242f","js/help.js":"fc9fb0517db2","js/tageditor.js":"450c9e8426fc","js/tageditornew.js":"9ac6c13a3a7f","js/inline-tag-editing.js":"30f72b99548b","js/revisions.js":"8c6bcd93b7fe","js/review.js":"37dd8dc83788"});

    </script>
</head>
<body class="login-page" style="cursor: default;"><style type="text/css">.login-page .script-only { display: block; }</style></body></html>
```

EDIT: Just noticed that this may be caused by the `document.write` call in the script of the page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the `runScripts: false` option for the browser fixed this because the `document.write` overwrote the body.

I've opened [an issue on their Github](https://github.com/assaf/zombie/issues/437) because this isn't the behavior other browsers display.

Comment: verified const browser = new Browser({runScripts: false});